# How to enter characters into a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, character

I'm trying to use a for loop to enter characters a-z into a string array, but I'm not having much luck converting characters to string values so they'll actually go into the string array. I keep getting null values as my output. Could anyone provide some tips on how to get characters into a string array? 
This is what I have so far:

```
  String[] letters = new String[26];
  for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
  {
     int i = 0;
     letters[i] = String.valueOf(ch);
     i++;
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

Comment: move `int i = 0;` outside the loop

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] letters = new String[26];
int i = 0;
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
{
   letters[i] = String.valueOf(ch);
   i++;
 }
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

Try this. i=0 should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move `int i = 0;` outside the loop like Eran said or just don't use another counter but determine index by ordinal character representation:

```
String[] letters = new String[26];
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    int index = (int) ch - 97;
    letters[index] = String.valueOf(ch);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

Additionally, you don't have to use another local variable and could just do `letters[(int) ch - 97] = ...` of course.

Answer (score 0):

your inserting each time to letters[0], keep Variable i outside the loop.

```
String[] letters = new String[26];
  int i = 0;
  for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
  {
     letters[i++] = String.valueOf(ch);
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++){
     int i = 0;
     letters[i] = String.valueOf(ch);
     i++;
}
```

You need to understand what it does : at EACH iteration you're initializing the variable `i` to `0` so you will never write in an other place than letters[0]

You need only to set it to 0, and then increment it, so just put the instruction before the loop

---

An other easy way would be only :

```
char[] letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
```

Comment: But she/he wants an array of strings not chars ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your particular purpose, with Java 8 Streams, you don't even need a loop.

```
String[] letters = IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z').mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char)i)).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

To break it down:

- `IntStream.rangeClosed(int, int)` makes a `Stream` of `int`s from the first `int` to the second, inclusive of both endpoints. We use this because there is no CharStream class (for some reason), but we can still use `char`s `'a'` and `'z'`, which will be implicitly converted to their `int` value.
- `mapToObj` takes a function which will convert each `int` of the `Stream` into an object. It gets a little messy here, as there is no single step conversion from `int` to `String`, we first need the `int` interpreted as a character value. So, we cast each `int` (named `i`) to a `char`, and then wrap that in a conversion from `char` to `String`: `i -> Character.toString((char)i)`. This will leave us with a `Stream<String>`.
- Now, we want the output to be `String[]`, as per your question. `Stream` has a `toArray` method, but this will give us an annoying `Object[]` result. Instead, we will supply the method we want to have used to build the array. We don't want anything fancy, so we'll just use the standard initializer for a `String` array: `toArray(String[]::new)`.

After that, `letters` will be equal to an array of `String`s, and each one will successively be a letter from `a` to `z`.

If you don't have access to Java 8 or simply don't like the above solution, here's a simplified version of your above code that removes the need for the index:

```
String[] letters = new String[26];
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) letters[c - 'a'] = Character.toString(c);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

In Java, `char`s can be treated as `int`s because below the surface, they are both stored as numbers.